# SQL Server stored procedure. insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The problem that I have is that 2 of my parameters that need to add into my table with a stored procedure are values that come from 2 other tables and I need to change these 2 values to the proper ones.

I have tried to search for the problem that I have but with no success.

There are 3 tables involved: `Movie`, `AgeRestriction` and `Price`.

Table `Movie`

- MovieID , int , PK
- Movie, varchar(50)
- Duration, time(0)
- AgeRestrictionID, int, FK - connected with the ID in the AgeRestriction table
- PriceID, int, FK - connected with the ID in the Price table

Table `AgeRestriction`:

- AgeRestrictionID , int, PK
- AgeRestriction, int

Table `Price`:

- PriceID, int, PK
- Price, int

The 2 values that i add is the value (`AgeRestriction, int`) from the `AgeRestriction` table and (`Price, int`) from the `Price` table.

This is how I need to insert the values I get into the table `Movies`.

```
 public void InsertMovie(Movie movie)
 {
        using (SqlConnection conn = CreateConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddMovie", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Movie", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = movie._movie;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Duration", SqlDbType.Time, 0).Value = movie.Duration;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AgeRestriction", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = movie.AgeRestriction;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50).Value = movie.Price;

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("An error occured in the data access layer.");
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I'm trying to create a stored procedure that can do all this but so far with no success so I'm asking you guys here..

Comment: Very unclear - does the stored procedure already exist? If yes, does it work on its own, when run from Mgmt Studio? Or do you need help writing that stored procedure? Or are you problems with *calling* that stored procedure from C#? Please **clarify!**

Comment: Is there any identity columns in any of these tables ?

Comment: I have tried to create a stored procedure on my own but need help to Create one that works. I am using Visual Stuido 2013. Yes, MovieID, AgeRestrictionID in the AgeRestriction table and PriceID in the Price table are identity columns. I need help creating a Stored procedure

Comment: OK, so please show us what you've tried so far. SO users are happy to help figure out issues and problems - but SO is **not** a code-writing service, you cannot expect to just define your needs and get the code done ready-to-use .....

Answer (score 0):

Okey, this is what ive tried:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddMovie]
@Movie varchar(50),
@Duration time(0),
@AgeRestrictionID int,
@PriceID int,
@AgeRestriction int,
@Price int
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO Movie (Movie, Duration, AgeRestrictionID, PriceID)
        VALUES (@Movie, @Duration, @AgeRestrictionID, @PriceID)
        SELECT Movie, Duration, AgeRestriction, Price
        FROM Movie AS M
        INNER JOIN AgeRestriction as Ag ON M.AgeRestrictionID = Ag.AgeRestrictionID
        INNER JOIN Price as P ON M.PriceID = P.PriceID

COMMIT
END
```